# Gtk crashes on adding and removing listboxrows

Tags: python, multithreading, listbox, gtk, pygtk

I want to create a Gtk program that requires to continuously update a `ListBox`, i.e. add and remove rows. I am trying this approach. It could be cleaner but here it is just long enough to explain the problem.

```
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

def add_widgets(listbox):

    # add 5 rows
    for _ in range(5):
        for _ in range(5):
            add_row(listbox)
        window.show_all()  # make the changes visible
        sleep(1)  # to make the change stay

        # remove all the rows
        for row in listbox.get_children():
            listbox.remove(row)
        window.show_all()
        sleep(1)
    
    # all the addition and removal done
    print('finished')

def add_row(listbox):
    listboxrow = Gtk.ListBoxRow()
    label = Gtk.Label()
    label.set_text("Hey There")
    listboxrow.add(label)
    listbox.add(listboxrow)

window = Gtk.Window()
window.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)
listbox = Gtk.ListBox()
window.add(listbox)
window.show_all()

# Thread to add and remove rows
update_thread = Thread(target=add_widgets, args=(listbox, ))
update_thread.start()

Gtk.main()
```

This code runs fine like 50% of the time. For the rest, it gives me 3 types of errors, all of them randomly.

1. The good old `SegFault` after like 2 or 3 iteration of the parent loop in `add_widgets`
2. The following:

```
**
Gtk:ERROR:../gtk/gtk/gtkcssnode.c:319:lookup_in_global_parent_cache: assertion failed: (node->cache == NULL)
Bail out! Gtk:ERROR:../gtk/gtk/gtkcssnode.c:319:lookup_in_global_parent_cache: assertion failed: (node->cache == NULL)
Aborted
```

3. The last one doesn't crash the program but it adds random number of rows instead. i.e. it adds 3(random) rows instead of 5, as specified or maybe no rows at all.

I've tried adding more sleep statements at appropriate places because initially, I thought, it could be because the windows are not ready when updating widgets.

I wanna know why its happening and how can I fix it.

**EDIT**: It's probably something to do with the UI and the thread synchronization because, it(the crash) happens more frequently when interacting with the window. For instance, when you are dragging it, it has more chances of crashing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must not call GTK+ code from other threads. All interactions must be done in the main thread. This is documented in https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Threads.html.

If you want to do some "background" updates of your widgets, you can simulate that with functions such as `g_idle_add()` (https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-idle-add), `g_timeout_add()` (https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add) and other related functions.

Comment: Kudos for the reference! I've used `g_timeout_add` in the past but as they're specifying, none of the functions are reliable for time critical jobs. Wouldn't that be a problem?

Comment: I mean on these beefy machines today, it doesn't really matter, it's reliable enough to go with but isn't there a way that's really **parallel**.

Comment: Can I do something like *nested threads*, if you know what I mean. What I'm saying is, start the job with `g_timeout_add` and then spawn maybe a couple threads to do the job if it's resource intensive. Would that be still thread safe? Considering all the updates are being made with the main thread. It's more like `runOnUiThread` coroutine in **Kotlin**, if you're familiar.

Comment: I tried both `g_timeout_add()` and `g_idle_add()` and none of them worked for my usecase. The window just freezes until all the updation is completed which is obvious being single threaded.

Comment: The nested thread thing is a bit better than the original approach but it still makes it crash a few times with the same errors. The crashes are just less frequent now.

Comment: Although I can't get the asynchronous behaviour I want, but your answer seems like the only correct way. I can make it work with some tweaks.

Comment: How did you warp your code with idle_add, did you get all the window updates? I would make a new function add_widgets_idle which just calls Glib.idle_add(add_widgets(listbox))

Comment: You can do work in other threads, you just can't update the UI. So you can spawn a thread, do a long calculation, and in the end schedule an update with `g_idle_add()` (which will run in the main thread).

Comment: Alternatively, if your long calculation actually consists of many short steps, you can process events between them to unfreeze the UI, using https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-General.html#gtk-events-pending